# Guava's expireAfterAccess cache on collection-view

Tags: java, caching, guava

The javadoc to `expireAfterAccess` method says:

> Specifies that each entry should be automatically removed from the
>   cache once a fixed duration has elapsed after the entry's creation,
>   the most recent replacement of its value, or its last access. Access
>   time is reset by all cache read and write operations (including
>   Cache.asMap().get(Object) and Cache.asMap().put(K, V)), **but not by
>   operations on the collection-views of Cache.asMap**

I have the following code:

```
Cache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterAccess(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = cache.asMap();
        map.put("a", "12345");
        System.out.println("First access: " + map.get("a"));
        System.out.println("Second access: " + map.get("a"));
        Thread.sleep(1900); //1.9 seconds
        System.out.println("Third access: " + map.get("a"));
        Thread.sleep(1000); //1 second
        System.out.println("Fourth access: " + map.get("a"));
        Thread.sleep(1500); //1.5 second
        System.out.println("Fivth access: " + map.get("a"));
```

And its output is:

```
First access: 12345
Second access: 12345
Third access: 12345
Fourth access: 12345
Fivth access: 12345
```

So, as we can see that access time is reseted also when we perform get operation on collection-view. What bolded phrase in javadoc means in such case?

Comment: The doc you quote specifically states: "Access time is reset by all cache read and write operations (including Cache.asMap().get(Object)..."  The docs state that you should get the results you're getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> operations on the collection-views of Cache.asMap

The *collections* exposed by `Map` that are *views* on the `Cache` are `keySet()`, `values()`, `entrySet()`. Iterating on any of those won't reset the access time, and neither will writing the value of a `Map.Entry` obtained through `entrySet()`.